# Kivy/Python exception: cannot open dropdown list on a hidden widget

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown

I'm building a UI for a touchscreen with many different screens.  One screen needs to have a dropdown list to select a language.  I've tried many ways of creating this dropdown to no success.  Most recently, I've gotten this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/revascharf/Documents/COLLEGE WORK/SENIOR YEAR/screensTest/screen.py", line 91, in <module>
presentation = Builder.load_file("screen.kv")
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 1842, in load_file
 return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 1921, in load_string
 self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 2082, in _apply_rule
 child = cls(__no_builder=True)
File "/Users/revascharf/Documents/COLLEGE WORK/SENIOR YEAR/screensTest/screen.py", line 85, in __init__
 ddbutt.bind(on_release=dropdown.open(self))
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/uix/dropdown.py", line 220, in open
 'Cannot open a dropdown list on a hidden widget')
kivy.uix.dropdown.DropDownException: Cannot open a dropdown list on a hidden widget
```

From what I've been able to read online, it seems like this might be an issue with screen manager and drop down being incompatible.  Can someone point me to where I'm going wrong?  The issue is surrounding the CreateProfileScreen.

screen.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class StartUserRunScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ManageUserProfilesScreen(Screen):
    pass

class InitialPanelConfigScreen(Screen):
    panel_connect = StringProperty()
    panelNo = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InitialPanelConfigScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.panel_connect = 'Connect Panel: ' + str(self.panelNo)

    def panelConnected(self):
        #python I2C code goes here to send actual address
        if self.panelNo < 20:
            self.panelNo += 1
            self.panel_connect = 'Connect Panel: ' + str(self.panelNo)

    def cancelButton(self):
        #app.root.current = 'settings'
        self.panelNo = 0
        self.panel_connect = 'Connect Panel: ' + str(self.panelNo)

class AdjustVolumeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CreateProfileScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateProfileScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        dropdown = DropDown()
        languages = ['English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Cantonese']

        for lang in languages:
            btn = Button(text='%r' % lang, size_hint_y=.26, size_hint_x=.085)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)
        ddbutt = ObjectProperty(None)
        ddbutt.bind(on_release=dropdown.open(self))
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(ddbutt, 'text', x))

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("screen.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

screen.kv:

```
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager
ScreenManagement:
    transition: sm.NoTransition()
    HomeScreen:
    SettingsScreen:
    StartUserRunScreen:
    ManageUserProfilesScreen:
    InitialPanelConfigScreen:
    AdjustVolumeScreen:
    CreateProfileScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Carter School Sensory Walk'
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .4}

        Image:
            source: 'SensoryWalkLogo.png'
            size_hint: .68, .68
            pos_hint: {'x': -.045, 'y': .09}

        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'settings'
            text: 'Settings'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .63, 'y': .33}

        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'startrun'
            text: 'Start User Run'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .63, 'y': .63}

        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'manageprofiles'
            text: 'Manage User Profiles'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .63, 'y': .48}

        Button:
            text: 'Exit'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .63, 'y': .18}
            on_press: exit()



<SettingsScreen>:
    name: 'settings'

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Settings'
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .4}

        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'home'
            text: 'Return Home'
            font_size: 17
            size_hint: .189, .09
            pos_hint: {'x': .811, 'y': 0}

        Button:
            text: 'Adjust Brightness'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .63}

        Button:
            text: 'Adjust Volume'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .48}
            on_press: app.root.current = 'volume'

        Button:
            text: 'Panel Replacement'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .63, 'y': .63}

        Button:
            text: 'Initial Panel Configuration'
            font_size: 17.5
            size_hint: .27, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .63, 'y': .48}
            on_press: app.root.current = 'initpanelconfig'

<StartUserRunScreen>:
    name: 'startrun'

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Select User'
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .4}

        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'home'
            text: 'Return Home'
            font_size: 17
            size_hint: .189, .09
            pos_hint: {'x': .811, 'y': 0}


<ManageUserProfilesScreen>:
    name: 'manageprofiles'

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Manage User Profiles'
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .4}

        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'home'
            text: 'Return Home'
            font_size: 17
            size_hint: .189, .09
            pos_hint: {'x': .811, 'y': 0}

        Button:
            text: 'Create New User Profile'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: .5, .15
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': .6}
            on_press: app.root.current = 'createprofile'

        Button:
            text: 'Edit Existing User Profile'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: .5, .15
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': .4}

        Button:
            text: 'Delete User Profile'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: .5, .15
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': .2}

<InitialPanelConfigScreen>:
    name: 'initpanelconfig'

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Initial Panel Configuration'
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .4}

        Button:
            text: 'Cancel'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .189, .09
            pos_hint: {'x': .811, 'y': 0}
            on_press:
                app.root.current = 'settings'
                root.cancelButton()

        Button:
            text: 'Panel Connected'
            font_size: 28
            size_hint: .3, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .1}
            on_press: root.panelConnected()

        Label:
            text: root.panel_connect
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .04}

<AdjustVolumeScreen>:
    name: 'volume'

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Settings: Volume'
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .4}

        Button:
            text: 'Return to Settings'
            font_size: 17
            size_hint: .189, .09
            pos_hint: {'x': .811, 'y': 0}
            on_press: app.root.current = 'settings'

<CreateProfileScreen>:
    name: 'createprofile'
    ddbutt: langbutt

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'New Profile'
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .4}

        Button:
            text: 'Create Profile'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: .26, .12
            pos_hint: {'x': .37, 'y': .03}

        Button:
            text: 'Cancel'
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: .189, .09
            pos_hint: {'x': .811, 'y': 0}
            on_press: app.root.current = 'manageprofiles'

        TextInput:
            size_hint: .26, .075
            pos_hint: {'x': .23, 'y': .71}
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: 'User Name:'
            font_size: 25
            pos_hint: {'x': -.38, 'y': .25}

        Label:
            text: ' Language \nPreference:'
            font_size: 23
            pos_hint: {'x': -.38, 'y': 0}

        Button:
            id: langbutt
            size_hint: .26, .085
            pos_hint: {'x': .23, 'y': .46}
            font_size: 20
            text: 'Choose a Language'
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a minimal example to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Did not figure out how to work around the dropdown issue, but found that for what I needed, a spinner would work just as well.  I was able to implement a spinner in place of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually call a function at the callback binding instead of just naming it, it will be called before anything is drawn, hence the widget is hidden.

So, it should be

```
on_release = dropdown.open
```

and an instance reference is passed for you implicitly.

In other words, you can't explicitly pass an argument like `self` to dropdown.open() like that, because the brackets execute a call to the function right then and there. If you want to pass args to a callback function, the documentation says you can do it using functools partial:
[kivy bind](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=bind)